# Oracle JDK 17 docker image vs openjdk:17-jdk-slim

Tags: docker, java-17

I am developing a microservice application using java 17.Now for docker image I need to choose between following two options

1. FROM openjdk:17-oracle
2. FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

I understand that slim version will create a lightweight image.But I still want to understand the pros and cons of oracle provided version's.

Which one will be suitable in terms of performance  while deploying in azure cloud?